# horizontally align group of nodes with respect to coordinate

Tags: tikz-pgf, horizontal-alignment, nodes

I have one node (or rather, a coordinate) and a couple of nodes which are aligned in one "row" (via `right=of`, `left=of`). They are aligned below each other (via `below right=of`),

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[
    auto,
    node distance = 1em and 2em,
    thick,
    every node/.style = {
      text width = 5em,
      top color = blue!60,
      bottom color = blue!60,
      rectangle,
      font = \sffamily,
      white
    }
  ]
  \coordinate (center);
  \node [above = of center,text width=10em] (T0) {test0};
  \node (T1) [below left = of center] {test1};
  \node (T2) [left = of T1] {test2};
  \node (T3) [right = of T1] {test3};
  \node (T4) [right = of T3] {test4};
\draw [black,thick]
(center) -- (T0)
(center) -| (T1)
(center) -| (T2)
(center) -| (T3)
(center) -| (T4);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

This gives

[image: align]

As you can see, the center (test0) is not properly aligned with the group of nodes below. All boxes are equally wide.

How to better align the nodes?

Comment: `\node (T1) [below left = 1em and 1em of center] {test1};
 \node (T2) [left = of T1] {test2};
 \node (T3) [below right = 1em and 1em of center] {test3};
 \node (T4) [right = of T3] {test4};` I would recommend the package `forest` for such graphs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With library `trees` of TikZ package this is very simple to obtain:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{trees}

\usepackage[active,tightpage]{preview}% just for showing image
\PreviewEnvironment{tikzpicture}
\setlength\PreviewBorder{5pt}%

    \begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[
thick,
every node/.style = {
      text width = 5em,
      top color = blue!60,
      bottom color = blue!60,
      rectangle,
      font = \sffamily,
      text=white
                    },
sibling distance = 7em,
edge from parent fork down                  
  ]
\node[text width=10em] (T0) {test0}
    child {node (T1) {test1}}
    child {node (T2) {test2}}
    child {node (T3) {test3}}
    child {node (T4) {test4}};
\end{tikzpicture}
    \end{document}
```

Result:

[image]

Answer (score 4):

Below I present two options using TikZ and one additional version using `forest`.

### First TikZ option

Since to place `T1` you used `below left=of center`, then you can locate `T3` symmetrically using `below right=of center`. Also, to have even separation between the nodes you have to use `below left=1em and 1em of center` and `below right=1em and 1em of center`

### Second TikZ option

Here I build the diagram from the bottom to the top. I place the nodes on the bottom layer evenly spaced and then use the `calc` library to find the middle point between the central nodes; I place an auxiliary coordinate and then use this to place the upper node and to draw the lines.

The code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning,calc}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[
    auto,
    node distance = 1em and 2em,
    thick,
    every node/.style = {
      text width = 5em,
      top color = blue!60,
      bottom color = blue!60,
      rectangle,
      font = \sffamily,
      white
    }
  ]
  \coordinate (center);
  \node [above = of center,text width=10em] (T0) {test0};
  \node (T1) [below left = 1em and 1em of center] {test1};
  \node (T2) [left = of T1] {test2};
  \node (T3) [below right = 1em and 1em  of center] {test3};
  \node (T4) [right = of T3] {test4};
\draw [black,thick]
(center) -- (T0)
(center) -| (T1)
(center) -| (T2)
(center) -| (T3)
(center) -| (T4);
\end{tikzpicture}\par\bigskip

\begin{tikzpicture}[
    auto,
    node distance = 1em and 2em,
    thick,
    every node/.style = {
      text width = 5em,
      top color = blue!60,
      bottom color = blue!60,
      rectangle,
      font = \sffamily,
      white
    }
  ]
  \node (T2) {test2};
  \node (T1) [right= of T2] {test1};
  \node (T3) [right= of T1] {test3};
  \node (T4) [right = of T3] {test4};
  \coordinate (center) at ([yshift=10pt] $ (T1.north)!0.5!(T3.north) $ );
  \node (T0) [above=10pt of center,text width=10em] {test0};
\draw [black,thick]
(center) -- (T0)
(center) -| (T1)
(center) -| (T2)
(center) -| (T3)
(center) -| (T4);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

The result:

[image]

### `forest` option

Since this seems like a tree, then you could use [`forest`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/forest) and leave the alignment to the package:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{forest}

\begin{document}
\begin{forest}
for tree={
text width = 5em,
top color = blue!60,
bottom color = blue!60,
rectangle,
font = \sffamily,
white,
parent anchor=south,
child anchor=north,
  edge path={
    \noexpand\path[\forestoption{edge}]
      (!u.parent anchor) -- +(0,-10pt) -|   
      (.child anchor)\forestoption{edge label};
  },
  l sep=20pt,
}
[test0,text width=10em
  [test2]
  [test1]
  [test3]
  [test4]
]
\end{forest}

\end{document}
```

[image]